# Is it at all possible to blur the status bar? By taking getting a UIImage representation of it or otherwise?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiimage

I'm having a great deal of trouble doing something that should theoretically be pretty simple given how common it is in iOS 7: blur the screen *as well as the status bar*.

You can get a `UIView` representation of it with `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`, but that won't convert to a `UIImage`. You can get a `UIImage` representation of the screen with `drawViewHierarchyInRect` but it doesn't include the status bar.

Is it at all possible to blur the status bar in iOS 7?